# What is the mean of This Code in js

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

what does the below coding mean?

```
        !-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
          <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a **knockout.js** code.

Magento 2 used knockout JS in several place like checkout, cart, UI component.

As per your query.

```
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
```

Above code is call template file using knockout. and below code is for get validation error message.

```
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
```

There are so many documentation available for knockout JS below is one of them.

- [devdocs.magento.com](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/concepts/knockout-bindings.html)
- [knockout-js-in-magento-2](https://inchoo.net/magento-2/knockout-js-in-magento-2/)

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Chirag's answer

`getRegion()` is mapped against `displayArea` node
In your example `displayArea` is `messages`

```
Example: <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
```

`getTemplate` is mapped against `template` node and call the template, in your example it will call all the templates

```
Example: <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/onepage</item>
```

`ko foreach:` and `ko template:` are `knockout js bindings`

The `foreach binding` duplicates a section of markup for each entry in an array, and binds each copy of that markup to the corresponding array item.

The `template binding` populates the associated DOM element with the results of rendering a template.